# How can I reverse the order of my blogger posts without changing the date?

Tags: javascript, html, rss, blogger, feed

I am constantly searching over the internet to reverse my blogger posts order.
What i found is by changing the posts dates but that really sucks if you have 100+ posts.

Is their any way to reverse its order without changing each post date?

Comment: why not use [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)?

Comment: I think this is not going to work with blogger.